# flatmap in a composite pattern

Tags: java, java-stream, composite, flatmap

I am learning design patterns and I stumbled upon a task that interested me, but I failed completing it. I have an interface Box, that has two extending class, let's call it Leaf and BoxContainer. I tried doing something like this:

```
List<Box> boxContainer = new BoxContainer(new Leaf("red","fresh"),
                                                new Leaf("white","dry"),
                                                new Leaf("black","dry"),
                                                new Leaf("green", "fresh"),
                                                new BoxContainer(("red","fresh"),
                                                new Leaf("white","dry"),
                                                new Leaf("black","dry"),
                                                new Leaf("green", "fresh"),)));
```

and one of the method i implemented needs to flatten the list into one long list, because when i try to sum up the size of the list it gives me 5, not 8 that i expect to get, since there are 8 leafs inside a box - 4 on the outside and another 4 inside the BoxContainer in the BoxContainer.
I'm trying to use flatmap because I wanted the method to be able to flatten more than 1 BoxContainer in a BoxContainer, I mean I would like to be able to pass a box in a box in a box in a box and so on, and the flatmap should help me do this as far as i understand.
The problem is that when I tried this :

```
List<Box> getBoxes() {
        List<Box>flat= allBoxes.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the List::stream gives me error "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

is there any way around it, or is my implementation and simply thinking bad and I should go about it in some other way?

I tried some lambda solutions and I browsed other examples of the problem but didn't find anything i could implement in my own code

@Edit

```
class BoxContainer implements Box{
     List<Box> allBoxes= new ArrayList<>();
    String color;
    String state;

    public BoxContainer(Box... boxes) {
        allBoxes.addAll(Arrays.asList(boxes));
    }
```

as for class/interface definitions :

```
interface Box { String getColor(); String getState(); }
```

Comment: What enables you to assign a `BoxContainer` instance to a `List<Box>`?  And an expected output would also help a well as your class and interface definitions.

Comment: @WJS I found something like this for composite pattern, dude which i snatched this from also used some streams to manipulate the data inside but he was mapping integers to calculate price, and my method does something else so i coulnd't borrow ready solution :(
```public CompositeBlock(Box... boxes) {
        allBoxes.addAll(Arrays.asList(boxes));
    }
```
as for class/interface definitions :

```
interface Box {
    String getColor();
    String getState();

}
```

Comment: Put the suggested edits and details in the question.

Comment: @WJS I did just that

Comment: So you want a stream of all the `Leaf`s, ignoring the `BoxContainer`s?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have nested flatMaps if you want it to be recursive. The simplest way is to provide a method on the `Box` interface that streams all its nested boxes:

```
Stream<Leaf> leaves();
```

On the `BoxContainer` class, it would iterate over its children:

```
@Override
Stream<Leaf> leaves() {
    return allBoxes.stream().flatMap(Box::leaves);
}
```

And the `Leaf` class just returns itself:

```
@Override
Stream<Leaf> leaves() {
    return Stream.of(this);
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/KzFMon)

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem that the Composite Pattern is intended to solve; i.e. a client calling the `leaves()` method is stuck figuring out whether each element in the Stream is a `Leaf` or `Container`. Worse, implementing the `leaves()` method of a `Leaf` to return itself leads to infinite recursion.

Comment: How is that? All you have to do is call `leaves().toList()` on your BoxContainer and you got a list of Leaf. You can even make it more explicit and return `Stream<Leaf>`.

Comment: @shmosel - this is what i've been looking for, thank You kind Sir

Comment: I guess the assumption is that a client can never invoke a method on a nested `Container`, which is probably fair. But a `Box` cannot return a `Leaf` because that forces the client to deal with two different abstractions, and the purpose of the Composite Pattern is to avoid that: "_Composite lets clients treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly._" Typically, the composition is treated as an individual object. This does the inverse, which is less helpful since the iteration logic remains the client's responsibility rather than abstracting that away.

Comment: Additionally, if the "uniform abstraction" of a composite was to return some collection of itself (as in the original implementation of this answer) then the client needs to know not to recurse into that resulting collection; i.e. the client needs to treat some instances of the abstraction differently from others, which is another form of the original problem the Composite Pattern tries to solve.